# DataGridView AutoFit and Fill

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 3 columns in my `DataGridView`. What I am trying to do is have the first 2 columns auto fit to the width of the content, and have the 3rd column fill the remaining space.

Is it possible to do in WinForms? I am loading my data from an EF DataContext if that's any use. I have included an image of how it currently looks.

[image]

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You need to use the [`DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

You can use one of these values for column 0 and 1:

> **AllCells:** *The column width adjusts to fit the contents of all cells in
>   the column, including the header cell.* 
>   **AllCellsExceptHeader:** *The column width adjusts to fit the contents of all cells in the column, excluding the header cell.* 
>   **DisplayedCells:**   *The column width adjusts to
>   fit the contents of all cells in the column that are in rows currently
>   displayed onscreen, including the header cell.* 
>   **DisplayedCellsExceptHeader:**   *The column width adjusts to fit the
>   contents of all cells in the column that are in rows currently
>   displayed onscreen, excluding the header cell.*

Then you use the **Fill** value for column 2

> *The column width adjusts so that the widths of all columns exactly fills the display area of the control...*

```
this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
this.DataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
this.DataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

---

As pointed out by other users, the default value can be set at `datagridview` level with [`DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

```
this.DataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
this.DataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
```

could be:

```
this.DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

---

**Important note:**

If your grid is bound to a datasource and columns are auto-generated (`AutoGenerateColumns` property set to True), you need to use the [`DataBindingComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) event to apply style **AFTER** columns have been created.

---

In some scenarios (change cells value by code for example), I had to call `DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();` to refresh the grid.

Comment: Works perfectly when using the DataBindingComplete event.

Comment: I can't figure how to call DataBindingComplete method after datagrid is populated

Comment: @Dan DataBindingComplete is not a *method*, it's an datagridview *event* to which you need to subscribe. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31685874/2387010 gives an example. Does it helps?

Comment: It would be helpful if the example was explained, but will suffice. The [MSDN article that you linked to in your post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) shows it as a method, which is what I used as my pattern but can't figure out how it gets called.

Comment: @Dan Yes, the MSDN example shows a method that use this specific event. I was thinking you already knew how to use events in .Net.  If needed, you could read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx) that deals with events. There are many ways to raise them.

Comment: @Chris that piece of missing information is definitely helpful, thanks. I am reading [this book](https://www.amazon.com/C-6-0-NET-4-6-Framework-ebook/dp/B015XFLAF0) and *just* got to the chapter on delegates and lambda functions so this will hopefully make more sense shortly. Thank you!

Answer (score 26):

This is my favorite approach...

```
_dataGrid.DataBindingComplete += (o, _) =>
    {
        var dataGridView = o as DataGridView;
        if (dataGridView != null)
        {
           dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
           dataGridView.Columns[dataGridView.ColumnCount-1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        }
    };
```

Comment: If column size =0, `index out of bound exception` just fix that, thanks!!

Answer (score 19):

**Just change Property from property of control:**
 `AutoSizeColumnsMode:Fill`

**OR By code**

`dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode=DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;`

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a solution like this one! :)

Answer (score 7):

<strike>Not tested but you can give a try.</strike> Tested and working. I hope you can play with `AutoSizeMode` of `DataGridViewColum` to achieve what you need.

Try setting

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = yourdatasource;<--set datasource before you set AutoSizeMode

//Set the following properties after setting datasource
dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

This should work

Comment: This doesn't work. I am setting it when the form initializes before the data source is added from the DataContext. Could that be why? I am not sure where to set it as the data is loaded at run time and the columns are taken from the EF model.

Comment: Looks like that but not, the third line doesn't work, I tested this 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @JamesJeffery you're AutoPopulating columns or manually populating?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I am using the dataGridView1.DataSource property to bind a List returned from my DataContext.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing,

```
 AutoSizeColumnMode = Fill;
```

Comment: for full syntax like this: `dataGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill`

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have done in order to get the column "first_name" fill the space when all the columns cannot do it.

When the grid goes to small the column "first_name" gets almost invisible (very thin) so I can set the `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode` property to `AllCells` as the others visible columns. For performance issues it's important to set them to `None` before data binding it and set back to `AllCells` in the `DataBindingComplete` event handler of the grid. Hope it helps!

```
private void dataGridView1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ColumnsWidth = 0;
    foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        if (col.Visible) ColumnsWidth += col.Width;
    }
    if (ColumnsWidth <dataGridView1.Width)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns["first_name"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    }
    else if (dataGridView1.Columns["first_name"].Width < 10) 
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns["first_name"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Fill(DataGridView dgv2)
   {
        try
        {
            dgv = dgv2;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dgv.Columns)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < GridCol.DataGridView.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    GridCol.DataGridView.Columns[j].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
                    GridCol.DataGridView.Columns[j].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                    GridCol.DataGridView.Columns[j].FillWeight = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is not great. First you don't need the nested loop, which sets the width mode of all the columns to the same thing many (<number of columns>) times; you can access the AutoSizeMode and FillWeight properties of each column directly from `GridCol`. Second it is setting the AutoSizeMode for each column to two different values; the second assignment will overwrite the first.

Answer (score 0):

To build on AlfredBr's answer, if you hid some of your columns, you can use the following to auto-size all columns and then just have the last visible column fill the empty space:

```
myDgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
myDgv.Columns.GetLastColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible, DataGridViewElementStates.None).AutoSizeMode = 
    DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void setHeight(DataGridView src)
{
    src.Height= src.ColumnHeadersVisible ? src.ColumnHeadersHeight : 0 +   src.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => row.Visible).Sum(row => row.Height);
}
```

Comment: just call that function, it will take care of deciding datagridview height based on number of rows in it

Comment: First of all, that does not answer the OP's question. Also (for future reference) include such comment on the answer itself (you can edit it).

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
  DGV.AutoResizeColumns();
  DGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode=DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```