# C# listBox size less then should be

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `listBox` and `dataGridView` in `tableLayoutPanel`. In editor their sizes looks same, but when I start application `listBox` height less then `dataGridView`. Both elements's `dock` property set to `Fill`.

In editor:
[image]

In fact:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try setting the `IntegralHeight` property on the listbox to `false`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks, it helped!

Comment: When `true`, as it is by default, this property tells the listbox that it must resize to fit a whole number of items.

Comment: Does `dataGridView`  have same property to fill with empty rows and last column width whole available space?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember.

Comment: Yes it has. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18666582/10216583) post and [DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewColumn_AutoSizeMode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try setting the `IntegralHeight` property on the listbox to `false`

— @500-InternalServerError