# How to fit all the cells to data grid view?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I need to fit in all the cells to the data grid view width

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataGridView AutoFit and Fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666582/datagridview-autofit-and-fill)

Answer (score 1):

Set "AutoSizeColumnsMode" on "Fill" from data grid view properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could set `dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill` or setting one to one column like `dt.Columns[index of column or "name of the column header"].Width = 30`